# Is BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted Thread Safe

Tags: .net, wpf, backgroundworker

Have a problem that is very hard to reproduce.
The exception is:

```
e.Exception.Message = Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
e.Exception.StackTrace 
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.MoveToPosition(GeneratorPosition position, GeneratorDirection direction, Boolean allowStartAtRealizedItem, GeneratorState& state)
at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.Generator..ctor(ItemContainerGenerator factory, GeneratorPosition position, GeneratorDirection direction, Boolean allowStartAtRealizedItem)
```

I catch that in App.cs App_DispatcherUnhandledException

I think that is from XAML as I have Break on Thrown turned on for every option in Visual Studio.
And I am pretty sure I have all the code behind wrapped in Try Catch.
For sure the page where I think the error is originating is catching all code behind exceptions.
If I break on the get for those public properties I cannot reproduce the error.
As I slow it down to try and debug then it is harder to reproduce.

Have some tabs where I display text using a TextBlock and formatted text using FlowDocumentViewer.

Source is bound to public properties.
The public property for the TextBlock.Text is RawText and the backing variable is rawText.

I get the text and information to format the text on a BackgroundWorker that is created on the UI thread..
Before calling the BackgroundWorker I set the rawText to "getting text" and call CancelAsync() if the BackgroundWorker IsBusy.
Then on RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler I set the rawText to the actual text. 
Then I only call notifypropertychanged if that tab is selected so it does not render if it is not visible.

Could the problem be that I am changing the rawText in the RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler  while the control is reading the rawText?   Or I am changing the rawText to "getting text" while the UI control is reading the text?

And other thoughts?

Would placing locks on those assignments fix it?

Not MVVM.

I thought I sufficiently described the code but apparently not.

```
rawText = "getting text";
backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(input);
```

then in RunWorkerCompleted

```
DocTextAndHighlight docTextAndHighlight = (GabeLib.DocTextAndHighlight)e.Result;
rawText = docTextAndHighlight.RawText;
```

NotifyPropertyChanged on RawText is only called if that tab is open.

Added Locks and cannot reproduce the error but that does not mean it is gone.
Will have to test in production.
Also added pass thru converts to the controls I suspect and write out a debug message.
I don't what is throwing the exception and the exception is telling me nothing.

This might be an old com component with a DDE interface.
One method call reports this exact same error.
It is a method call that only fails 1 in 10,000.
But if it fails it will fails in blocks.
And that call is in a try catch block but for some reason it is not caught in the direct block. 
Granted the error has very little information but it is the exact same error. 
The bad part is that it crashes the app.
I can set e.Handled = true; but it still throws the error enough times to crash the app.

Comment: Vote to close?  What else do you need?  I don't know which line is throwing the exception so I don't know which code to post.  As I state I think it is coming from rendering.

Comment: Two votes to close?  What information do you need?

Comment: We need repro code, something we can run ourselves and debug.  The stack trace is completely inadequate.  Right now it isn't even clear whether this is just another exception that WPF swallows, it does a lot of that.  Untick the Thrown checkbox and you'll be a happier WPF user.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry I cannot create a simple example that reproduces the problem.  It is not non fatal exception.   This is an app that is crashing on this condition and right now that is all I know about the exception.  I know you know .NET.  What is nature of Backgroundworker.RunWorkerComplete?   Maybe I am not asking the question correctly but does it block. Can a safely assign a variable in RunWorkerComplete and also in a another method or set on the main thread?

Comment: The `RunWorkerCompleted` event executes on a threadpool thread, so it can be running concurrently with the main thread. It does not block execution of the UI thread, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes that is what I am asking.  Is the fix to place locks on those variables?

Comment: I don't know. Possibly. Without seeing code, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: @JimMischel I added code sample.  I will try locks but locks is not something I have ever used before so I am asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DoWork will run on a thread pool thread and RunWorkerCompleted will run on the UI thread, provide that your BackgroundWorker was created on the UI thread.

And from MSDN:

> Your RunWorkerCompleted event handler should always check the AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Error and AsyncCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled properties before accessing the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property. If an exception was raised or if the operation was canceled, accessing the RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Result property raises an exception.(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx):

Comment: Locks as fix was a reach. My BackgroundWorker is created on the UI thread.